# How do I change my VS Report layout so that when it renders in my website it is centered and fills the screen?

Tags: html, width

I have project that has about 29 reports. These reports all render on a website. When the report renders in the website, it is left-aligned and only fills about 1/3 of the screen (width-wise). Is there some way to 
(1) center align the report
(2) make the report full width of screen ( or 2/3 rds of screen)

Thank you

I have scoured the internet, but I can't find anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your code to understand more.
But seems its more of a CSS problem

```
.report{ 
margin:0 auto  /* Aligns box to center*/
width:100%;
text-align:center /* Aligns text to center*/
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
/*/*/*/*/*/  bunch of code here ( aprox. 2,000 lines of code)  */*/*/*/*/

    </EmbeddedImage>
  </EmbeddedImages>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>424bd8be-7135-47d4-83a1-3ca86189de41</rd:ReportID>
</Report>